# Trying to properly setup minify php for multiple groups

Tags: php, minify

Here is the situation:

Some pages on my site use different js files than other. For instance:
Page A uses jquery and jqueryui
Page B uses jquery, jqueryui and jquery validation
Page C uses jquery, jqueryui, jquery qtip

Now I have created groups in minify's groupsConfig.php like this:

```
'mainjs' => array(
                '//ext/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js',
                '//ext/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.6.min.js'
                ),
'pageA' = > array(
                '//ext/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js',
                '//ext/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.6.min.js',
                '//ext/jquery/jquery-validation.js'
                ),
```

My question is..that if I get different pages to load different js groups doesn't that sort of defeat the purpose of caching it on the client?

For example one page might load like this `/min/g=mainjs` while the other one will load `/min/g=pageA` etc etc.

---

UPDATE: I may have found a concept for how it should work.. Please see here: http://www.mrclay.org/2008/09/19/minify-21-on-mrclayorg/#comment-101896

Any idea on how to accomplish what the commentator did?

Comment: Using that method, it seems like each different page will have its own cached `.js` file containing everything. I think you're defeating the purpose by trying it this way.

Comment: I guess it will still cache, but different cache for different page.

Comment: @jnpcl: That's exactly where I am confused. Even if I were to load only one additional file for pageA and then the call 2 groups at a time like this: `min/g=mainjs,pageA` ...isn't that the same thing as well?

Comment: You might as well just minify **all** of your scripts into one, and use that on every page.

Comment: @jnpcl: Can't and don't want to do that. Someone left a comment here: http://www.mrclay.org/2008/09/19/minify-21-on-mrclayorg/#comment-101896 --Any idea on how they accomplished that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is the work around I came up with.

1) I created a group called generaljs (for javascript) and a group called generalcss (for css) and basically have all the files I need across the entire site into that.

2) For other pages such as Page A and Page B and Page C I created respective groups for those called pageajs and pageacss

3) On pages where I don't need page A's javascript and css file I just loaded them at the end of body so it would be ready via cache when the visitor goes to Page A. Rinse and repeat for other pages as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google APIs for [better caching and other good reasons](http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is a generic question and I used jquery as an example so this is not helpful at all for me.